# RVM + Ruby 1.9.1 + ruby-debug = error?

Tags: ruby, textmate, rubygems, rvm, ruby-debug

I am trying to get a decent navigation between my methods in TextMate. I would love to have a list of them in a drawer, but I guess there is no such solution yet, right? Therefore I am trying to set up `RubyAMP` to work with `Ruby 1.9.1-p378` installed via `RVM`, but have some troubles. RubyAMP needs `ruby-debug`, and here is what I get if I try to install the gem

```
$ rvm gem install ruby-debug
info: ruby-1.9.1-p378: ruby 1.9.1p378 (2010-01-10 revision 26273) [x86_64-darwin10] 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...

ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/Users/andrei/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/ruby extconf.rb
Can't handle 1.9.x yet
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

However, [the gem page](http://github.com/mark-moseley/ruby-debug) says that it should work with 1.9.x. How can I fix it?

Comment: It didn't help. I am confused by `Can't handle 1.9.x yet`. Does it come from `ruby-debug`? Or it is another component?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this(from https://rvm.io/support/troubleshooting):

```
rvm gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include="$rvm_src_path/ruby-1.9.1-p378/"
```

Comment: In my case $rvm_src_path was undefined. Search for vm_core.h in your rvm area, its directory is the one you might need. Mine was /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p180

Comment: ruby-debug19 require linecache19 and linecache19 require Ruby ver. >= 1.9.2. Do you know another workaround ? NB: rvm gem install linecahce19 -- --with-ruby-include="$rvm_src_path/ruby-1.9.1-p378/" fails because require ruby 1.9.2. Thanks in advantage.

Answer (score 5):

The latest ruby 1.9.2-p0 runs `gem install ruby-debug19` without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest ruby 1.9.2-preview3

```
gem install ruby-debug19 -- --with-ruby-include="$rvm_src_path/ruby-1.9.2-preview3"
```